# Generate piecewise function using for loop

Tags: functions, piecewise, procedural-programming

I want to specify a piecewise function by writing `f[x_]:=Piecewise[piecewiseComponents]`, and use a loop to specify the components. I have tried

```
piecewiseComponents = {};
For[j = 1, j < 10, j++,
 leftBound = 0.1 j;
  rightBound = 0.1 (j + 1);
  piecewiseComponents = 
  Append[piecewiseComponents, {{RandomReal[{0, 10}], 
     leftBound < x < rightBound}}];
 ]
f[x_] := Piecewise[Flatten[piecewiseComponents, 1]]
```

Then I try to evaluate f at a certain x value

```
f[1]
```

what I get is not f[1] but I just get the list of piecewise components back.

I think this is because f doesn't seem to understand that I am passing in {val,cond} pairs and so doesn't know how to pass the input x into cond. How do I fix this?

Comment: try using `f[x_] := Evaluate@Piecewise[Flatten[piecewiseComponents, 1]]`? (and add `ClearAll[f,x,piecewiseComponents]` before your code block).

Comment: @kglr That worked!! Thanks. Can you tell me what role Evaluate plays here?

Comment: jcm, `Evaluate`  _"forces evaluation of the right-hand side of a delayed definition"_. See [SetDelayed >> Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).